# In SignalR Core using ChannelWriter: Do I need to call TryComplete twice if there's an exception?

Tags: c#, multithreading, channel, asp.net-core-signalr, system.threading.channels

Here is an excerpt from the [Use streaming in ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-2.2) article by Microsoft:

```
private async Task WriteItemsAsync(
    ChannelWriter<int> writer,
    int count,
    int delay,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            // Check the cancellation token regularly so that the server will stop
            // producing items if the client disconnects.
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            await writer.WriteAsync(i);

            // Use the cancellationToken in other APIs that accept cancellation
            // tokens so the cancellation can flow down to them.
            await Task.Delay(delay, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        writer.TryComplete(ex);
    }

    writer.TryComplete();
}
```

If there's an exception, it will first call writer.TryComplete(ex), and then writer.TryComplete(). In other words, it calls TryComplete (albeit different overloads) twice.

Is this necessary? Should I add a return statement after writer.TryComplete(ex) to avoid calling it twice? Or does the second writer.TryComplete() serve some meaningful purpose after calling the former?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary. This isn't the best example of a channel producer. `writer.TryComplete()` should be the last call of the `try{}` block :

```
private async Task WriteItemsAsync(
    ChannelWriter<int> writer,
    int count,
    int delay,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            // Check the cancellation token regularly so that the server will stop
            // producing items if the client disconnects.
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            await writer.WriteAsync(i);

            // Use the cancellationToken in other APIs that accept cancellation
            // tokens so the cancellation can flow down to them.
            await Task.Delay(delay, cancellationToken);
        }
        writer.TryComplete();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        writer.TryComplete(ex);
    }   
}
```

This way, it's only called once, either when the loop terminates succesfully or when an exception is thrown for any reason.

Instead of throwing on cancellation with `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` you could simply break out of the loop :

```
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        break;
    }
    await writer.WriteAsync(i);
    await Task.Delay(delay, cancellationToken);
}
writer.TryComplete();
```

In case of bounded channels, `WriteAsync` should also receive the cancellation token, otherwise it may get stuck if the channel is full:

```
await writer.WriteAsync(i,cancellationToken);
```